# How do I align the text on the left side and the icon on the right side?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to align the name of the food and the price to the left side and the Icon to the right. I can't seem to get it with `Row`, `Stack`, or a mixture of `Container` and `Column` Widgets.

Here is the code:

```
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 175,
            height: 175,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: img)),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(name,
                      style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("\$" + price.toString(),
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          )),
                      Text("/kg",
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 32)
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is what it looks right now: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/626321327791538188/727585975349280889/Capture10.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force widgets in `Column`s and `Row`s to take up as much available space as possible with the [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html), and [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)(which is just an empty expanded) widgets. There are multiple ways to accomplish what you need, each with their own benefits, but should all accomplish what you need.

Probably the easiest method is to add a `Spacer` in between the `Icon` and `Column` containing `Text`:

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
  Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(name,
        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        )),
      SizedBox(height: 4),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("\$" + price.toString(),
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              )),
          Text("/kg",
            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
            fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ))
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 32)
  ],
),
```

The alternative is to wrap either the `Column` containing `Text` or `Icon` in `Expanded`, though I would recommend wrapping the `Column` to give the `Text` extra room.

```
Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(name,
                        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 4),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("\$" + price.toString(),
                            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                            fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            )),
                        Text("/kg",
                            style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            ))
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 32)
            ],
          ),
```